# Hide image from Activity to BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to hide image from `ListView` , Here i have used custom listview with `BaseAdapter` 
Please see below image , Here on click of `Edit btn` **Image 1** should be visible ,

**ListView image is as follow**

[image: ListView image]

I have done this code from `Activity` on click of `button`

```
             ++btnClick;
            if (btnClick % 2 == 0) 
            {  
                textView.setText("Edit");
                baseAdapter.holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                textView.setText("Done");
                Log.e("call", "Done");
baseAdapter.holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            };
```

where `baseAdapter` is Object of `BaseAdapter` , Here what happens on click of button only **last button Invisible** as it is getting last reference , i don't want to reaload `BaseAdapter` again.

**BaseAdapterFavotites.java**

```
public class BaseAdapterFavotites extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;
public ArrayList<String> getSchoolId, getSchoolName;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
public ViewHolder holder;
Context context;
public String s;
HashMap<String, String> mapSchoolToLink = new HashMap<String, String>();;

public BaseAdapterFavotites(Context context,
    ArrayList<SearchResults> results, ArrayList<String> arrayId,
    ArrayList<String> arraySchoolName) {
    searchArrayList = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    getSchoolId = arrayId;
    this.context = context;
    getSchoolName = arraySchoolName;
}

public int getCount() {
    return searchArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_for_favorites,
                null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtSchoolNameList = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.schoolNameFav);

        holder.imgPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    holder.txtSchoolNameList.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
            .getschoolNameFromList());

    Log.e("holder", searchArrayList.get(position).getschoolNameFromList());

    holder.imgPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mapSchoolToLink.clear();
            searchArrayList.remove(position);
            getSchoolId.remove(position);
            getSchoolName.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.e("inside base", searchArrayList.toString());
            Log.e("inside getSchoolId", getSchoolId.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < getSchoolId.size(); i++) {
                mapSchoolToLink.put(getSchoolName.get(i),
                        getSchoolId.get(i));
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context
                    .getSharedPreferences("mytest", 0).edit().clear();
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : mapSchoolToLink.entrySet()) {
                editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            editor.commit();

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtSchoolNameList;
    public ImageView imgPhoto;
}

}
```

i have to hide image from `Activity` to `BaseAdapter` any solution for this

Comment: 1st: you want to **hide** or make it **invisible**? If hide then use View.GONE and if want to make it invisible then use View.INVISIBLE

Comment: exact thats i want to do

Comment: use baseAdapter.holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);

Comment: @Paresh i want to "Invisible" that image but my code is working for last one only

Comment: @Dhaval Sodha Parmar  read my question dude i have done same

Comment: when edit btn click all images has to be hide from listview, is it?

Comment: @robinhood yes and on click it should be visible that why i have done this code in Activity ++btnClick;
    if (btnClick % 2 == 0) {
     textView.setText("Edit");
     baseAdapter.holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else {
     textView.setText("Done");

     Log.e("call", "Done");
     baseAdapter.holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

Comment: I think your show/hide logic should be in the "getView()" method of the adapter.  Try this:  When the button is pressed, call "invalidate()" on the listView.  This will cause a re-draw of each item in the list.

Comment: tried buddy still work for last item only

Comment: @EJK is it better than `notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Comment: It appears as if you have only a single holder.  I say this because your code shows it as an attribute of the adapter.... If this is the case, then the holder is referring to only a single imageview.  You should have a holder for each row/view in the list.

Comment: @oldergod - Dunno.  I arbitrarily chose ListView.invalidate() over notifyDataSetChanged().  Both work.  I never took the time to look at which one is better/preferrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flags to manage visibility and check flag value in getView in adapter. In both cases  if(convertView==null) and else part also.

and on click of edit button set flag value to false and `ListView.invalidate()` or `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a field variable in your Adapter, *not* your Activity, that controls whether the Images are visible or not, call it `inEditMode`. In `getView()` use your:

```
if(inEditMode) {
    holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else {
    holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Whenever you toggle the state of `inEditMode` you must call `notifyDatasetChanged()` to update the entire ListView.

---

**Addition**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Recycling and View Holder code...

    holder.txtSchoolNameList.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
            .getschoolNameFromList());

    Log.e("holder", searchArrayList.get(position).getschoolNameFromList());

    if(inEditMode) {
        holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        holder.imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // Setting an OnClickListener that should happen in (convertView == null) { ... }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: buddy i have set Edit Button in activty

Comment: "Buddy" "read my" answer "dude", you must use the Adapter not the Activity.

Comment: @Rstar - see my comment above.  I think the problem may be that your holder is at the adapter level.  Thus you only have a reference to a single image.  You need to have a holder for each row in the list.

Comment: @Rstar then you know why *"Here what happens on click of button only last button Invisible as it is getting last reference"* and what's up with all the "dude" and "buddy" stuff ?

Comment: see my updated adapter code cause i am operating on click event from activty i dont want to call adapter again  and i want to hide images from adapter

Comment: @oldergod1 yes buddy i know cause it is getting last reference from activity but i want to hide all images from activity that is set from BaseAdapter

Comment: "i dont want to call adapter again" When you hide/show _each_ ImageView the OS redraws _each_ row... So there is no reason to build a complicated alternative method that will redraw every row but _not_ use the Adapter. Simply use the Adapter and call `notifyDataSetChange()`.